# Change button style to custom xml file by overriding android studio default button style

Tags: java, android-studio

I want custom button design to my button but android stdio has default button style which has purple color and I am not able to remove that.

My xml code of design:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/teal_200"
        android:endColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

Default button style is:
[Default Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqJcC.png)

Design I want to my button:
[My Button Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEM2M.png)

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. your solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can be added

```
android:centerColor
```

like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#00e0d1"
        android:centerColor="#2fc1ea"
        android:endColor="#C791F8"
        android:angle="270"/>
    <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
</shape>
```

after if you can add your button background

```
android:background
```

like this

```
   <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/custom_bg"/>
```